# Aurora Serverless Mysql Read Replica

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

How to separate read traffic from the rds database. Serverless doesn't have read replica. Already the production load is too high and it is not able to handle at the moment. I have to implement business reports. Can use clone? Any advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

Since Amazon Aurora serverless option does not have separate replicas, you can manually scale up the cluster with more ACUs to get more resources for the workload.
Clone would have initially the same data, but as the data changes on the source cluster, clone would divert from the same and might not help with the purpose.

If the workload is predictable, and needs more replicas, I would recommend switching to an Aurora provisioned cluster where you can create upto 15 replicas.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted more points to move to provisioned to separate read traffic